# cURL, работа с api vk

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, curl

Написала рабочий скрипт с использованием `file_get_contents`, где пользователь аутентифицируется и выводятся фото из его альбомов. Но потом мне сказали, что вместо `file_get_contents` лучше использовать cURL. И я пыталась, в результате получая ошибку:

> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Code is invalid or
>   expired."}

Например, пыталась получить `access_token`:

```
$data = array(
    'client_id' => $app_id,
    'client_secret' => $app_key,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    'code' => $_GET["code"]
);

$string = http_build_query($data);

$ch = curl_init(); // открывает сессию
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://oauth.vk.com/access_token"); // задает настройки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
$output = curl_exec($ch); // отправляет запрос
curl_close($ch); // закрывает сессию
print_r($output);
```

Пожалуйста, объясните как правильно это сделать. Что-то я совсем не понимаю как им пользоваться. Возможно, проблема в названии метода в конце url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Получение access_token](https://vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user?f=4.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20access_token)

Ваша ошибка в том, что Вы отправляете параметры в `$_POST`, а нужно в `$_GET`, т.е.:

```
$data = array(
    'client_id' => $app_id,
    'client_secret' => $app_key,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    'code' => $_GET["code"]
);

$string = http_build_query($data);

$ch = curl_init(); // открывает сессию
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?".urldecode($string)); // задает настройки
$output = curl_exec($ch); // отправляет запрос
curl_close($ch); // закрывает сессию
print_r($output); //ответ в json
$token = json_decode($output, true);
var_dump($token);
```